# Change openelec settings via ssh?

Tags: ssh, openelec, samba

So, i found myself with a raspberry with openelec installed at my father's house, my tv remote doesn't work via hdmi cec and i can't find a mouse anywhere home, so I can't navigate around the menus or use the pi.

If i could just open the pi http access i could use my phone as a remote with the Kore app and everything would be solved.

I tried looking around at the Openelec wiki but i couldn't find anything about it, only a mention of a config.txt file, but it didn't have anything useful for me.

Does anybody know how would i do that via ssh or any other way? I have my laptop with me and the raspi has ssh and Samba access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Kodi's docs](http://kodi.wiki/view/web_interface) on the web interface:

**Method 1 / guisettings.xml**

> Edit the guisettings.xml file in the userdata folder and look for the
>   following settings under `<services>`, and make sure they are set to
>   "true". You'll have to look for them a little bit, because there among
>   several other settings. Assuming you have not set a password or
>   changed other default settings, this should work:
>
> ```
>        <esallinterfaces> - true
>        <webserver> - true
>        <zeroconf> - true
> ```
>
> Save the file and restart Kodi.

**Method 2 / advancedsettings.xml**

> While using an advancedsettings.xml file might be easier to enable
>   these services, doing so will hide them from the normal Kodi GUI. You
>   will have to remove or edit the advancedsettings.xml file to turn
>   these settings back off, which can be confusing later on if you forgot
>   you have an advancedsettings.xml file.
>
> Create a plain text file (no rich text formatting, don't use .doc,
>   etc) and save it as advancedsettings.xml. Make sure that the file
>   extension is ".xml" and not ".txt" or ".xml.txt". Cut and paste this
>   into your new plain text file:
>
> ```
>     <advancedsettings>
>         <services>
>             <esallinterfaces>true</esallinterfaces>
>             <webserver>true</webserver>
>             <zeroconf>true</zeroconf>
>         </services>
>     </advancedsettings>
> ```
>
> Save this file in your userdata folder
>
> Note: If you have an existing advancedsettings.xml file, make sure the
>   tags are between the main  tags.
>
> Restart Kodi.

Comment: Oh, damn i missed that.. sorry for the inconvenience. Everything is solved now, thanks for your help!